# How do I get rid of vertical space above an unordered list?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

```
\newcommand{\stuff}[2]{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item #1
    \item #2
  \end{itemize}
}
```

When I use this command:

```
\stuff
   {Hello}
   {World}
```

The list has a large vertical space above it. I cannot change it by using `\vspace` either. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

That space is called `\topsep`. If you make it zero, then the items look more separated vertically (ugly). So control `\itemsep` also.

You can load `enumitem` package and customize various spaces easily. For details, refer to its manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\stuff}[2]{%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep] % or [topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]
    \item #1
    \item #2
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}
  Here is some text for demo
  \stuff{Hello}{World}
  Some again here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nope, still have the space.

Comment: @dopatraman If you compile my code as such, are you getting space? If no, you have to show your full (minimal) code like I did.

Comment: I'm setting `\itemsep` like this: `\setlength{\itemsep}{20pt}` is that correct?

Comment: I've shown you all of the code

Comment: @dopatraman Two things: your code is not compilable (like mine) and to change parameters of a list, it is better to use `enumitem`. Please add the code starting from `\documentclass` and ending at `end{document}` so that we can copy paste and test.